# Does this recurrence relation have a solution?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to know if there is an explicit solution to the following recurrence relation:

$f(n+1) = \frac{1}{2} (f(n)^2 + 1)$

with the intial condition $f(1) = 3$.

Comment: Ohhh now you edit it that makes much more sense (I'll fix my solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://oeis.org/A053630, it would seem unlikely.

Comment: As Amarnath Murthy commented in the OEIS page, using the numbers of the sequence, $\log(\log(f_n))$ is very close to $a+bn$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Amarnath Murthy's comment was `a(1) = 3, a(n+1) = (1/4)[{a(n)-1}^2 + {a(n)+1}^2]` while $a(n) = \text{floor}\left[2 \times 1.597910218031873...^{2^n}\right]$ was by Michael Somos